# Cancel previous request in YUI datatable search

Tags: datatable, yui

I am using YUI datatable. When user search for anything and type 1234, then it sends 4 request for 1,2,3,4. It works fine if response from server is fast but in some places response from server takes around 30 sec. Sometimes response from 4th request comes earlier than 3rd request and results in table looks very unpredictable. Is YUI provides anyway where i can cancel previous request for datatable, so that only results from last request shows in datatable.

Comment: Can you help with a little more information? Which version of YUI are you using? How are you requesting the information? Are you using a DataTableDataSource plugin?

Comment: I am using yui version 2.8.1. I am using YAHOO.util.DataSource and YAHOO.widget.DataTable to populate my datatable. This is normal yui datatable. I am not using any other plugin.